# NodeJS mysql's Textrow returns undefined even though it's a valid object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a funciton called `getSpidFromOvr()`

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
async function gopher(param1, param2){
    let param3 = parseInt(param1 - ovrUpgrade[param2 - 1]);

    const db = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        database: 'default_schema'
    });

    db.connect();
    let res = await db.query({
        sql: "SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `param` = ? LIMIT 1",
        values: [param3]
    });
    db.end();
    return await res;
}
```

which I call in my `main()` function,

```js
function main(){
    // First, get the ovr
    gopher(101, 5)
    .then((res) => {
        let row = res[0]; // [ TextRow { id: 100 } ]
        console.log(row.id); // Returns undefined
    })
}
```

Why is it that `row` returns a valid object (using `typeof row` returns `object`) but when I try to access the element `id` of `row`, it returns `undefined`?

Comment: please console.log your res and see what the output really is

Comment: @EugenSunic The commented part is the result of `console.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of doing

```js
res[0].id
```

I did

```js
res[0][0].id
```

Certainly a bit weird since I was able to call `res[0].id` if I were to use the callback function, but hope this helps anyone who comes across this issue.